# Why is this Django Template not receiving the context?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-templates

I'm using a simple view to render an 'index.html' page, and pass a JSON in the context variable.

```
def index(request):
    """Homepage. Calls are made to other classes from here."""
    ytv = YoutubeVideos()
    user = request.GET.get('user', '')
    videos = {'name': 'filler data here'}
    if user != '':
        videos = ytv.get(request=request, channel_data=1)
        print(videos)
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=videos)

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=videos)
```

I've confirmed it is going through the first return, with the videos context containing JSON data. It is printing in the console.

I also have the index.html file, which contains:

```
...
{{videos|json_script:'name'}}


<script>
    'use strict';

    var videos = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('name').textContent);

...
```

I've tried several variations on the way to get the JSON data in the Javascript including:
`<input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="videos" value="{{ videos }}">`
Then getting the value in javascript this way,
`var myVar = document.getElementById("myVar").value;`

The problem is when the html is rendered it becomes this (screenshot of Source):
[image: view of source]

Basically, the variable looks like it doesn't exist when it gets rendered.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the videos data like this :

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'videos': videos} )
```

And in templates you will get it.

Comment: I have tried that variation as well, with no luck. It's the exact same result.

Comment: I would guess that you have multiple videos, so you need to use a for loop to loop over your videos in the template.

Comment: 'videos' is a JSON with 4 items on the first layer, and many more nested below that. I can't access any of it.

Comment: @AlexGriffith did you fix your template as well?

Comment: If you have multiple videos your approach is not going to work.

Comment: `return render(request, 'index.html', {'videos': videos} )` will send videos... try to print just {{ videos }} in template and check if you are getting the value...